# Kafka Spout fails to acknowledge message in storm while setting multiple workers

Tags: apache-storm, topology

I have a storm topology that subscribes events from Kafaka queue. The topology works fine while the number of workers config.setNumWorkers is set to 1. When I update the number of workers to more than one or 2, the KafkaSpout fails to acknowledge the messages while looking at storm UI. What might be the possible cause, I am not able to figure out, the exactness of problem.

I have a 3 node cluster running one nimbus and 2 supervisors.

Comment: is it replaying the messages ? also are you getting a proper acknowledgement while running with single worker ?

Comment: Yes I am getting the proper acknowledgement while running with single worker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem got resolve. The reason being kafka unable to acknowledge the spout message was the conflict with the Hostname. I had mistakenly the same host name in /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts file of the both workers. When I check the worker I was able to get the exception - unable to communicate with host. So there by  I figured out, the problem was was host name .I updated the host name in etc/hosts mapping and /etc/host name file. The message started to be acknowledged. Thank you.